# Using shapefiles with CIvi

Tags: geocoding

I have a client evaluating Civi and they need voting district data to be in their contact records. If they have shapefiles for districts and full addresses in contact records, how much of a challenge is it to use those data points to populate a field for district?

I have looked in the docs for info about using shapefiles (no luck), and seen threads about identifying addresses within country borders, which suggest that it will be possible. But I don't have a sense of how hard/expensive it would be, which is an eval criteria we need.

Does anyone have insights they can share on this? Thank you!!

Comment: There are folk at the Australian Greens who have done a lot in this sort of area. If you want to join chat.civicrm.org you could ping @seamuslee

Comment: Thank you @petednz-fuzion! I will pass this info along and have my clients reach out.